# Why generators don't raise StopIteration exception when called through pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, generator

Consider the generator:

```
def sample():
    print("Setup")
    yield
    print("Teardown")


gen = sample()
next(gen)
next(gen)
```

When I call the first next(gen), the generator executes until print("Setup") and the next time I call it, it executes until after print("Teardown"). But also, since there is no second yield statement, it raises StopIteration exception. But when I do the following modification:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def sample():
    print("Setup")
    yield
    print("Teardown")


def test_case(sample):
    print("Executing test case")
```

Now, when I run the pytest command, all the code executes properly, first the setup part, then the test_case and then the teardown part. I am sure pytest is calling the generator twice during execution since all the print statements are being executed. But how is it that the StopIteration exception not being raised here? My assumption is that pytest is handling it internally. Confirm my assumption and please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder what you have expected instead. That every test fails because pytest didn't use the generator properly?

Comment: @KlausD. I think the question is about how the decorator works so as to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code to @pytest.fixture in [fixtures.py.](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/b90da34a86542c29f942bdf32ff05a142fbebd3e/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L908)

`@pytest.fixture` is a decorator, so it creates a new function that looks exactly like `sample()`, but that has a wrapper around it. The first time the `sample()` is called, the wrapper expects the function to return normally.  The second time `sample()` is called, it is expecting the function to return `StopIteration`, and explicitly discards it.

In general, you should not expect a function that has a decorator to behave the same way as that same function without a decorator.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! So, would it still be wrong to say on a higher level that pytest is handling it by using the fixture decorator?

Answer (score 1):

`next()` is low-level and `StopIteration` is low-level too. Those are parts of the iteration protocol. The other side must obey the rules too, a `StopIteration` must be caught (or it becomes a `RuntimeError` - PEP479).

The `StopIteration` exception is always raised at the end of the generator and if you don't see an error, the caller must have caught the exception directly (`try-except`) or indirectly, e.g.:

```
gen = sample()
# the for statement speaks the iteration protocol
# behind the scenes
for v in gen:
    print(f"got {v}")
```

Comment: I had a similar assumption. Thanks for clarifying it. I knew this was handled internally during for loops, but I was not aware how pytest dealt with this. So I had to confirm. Thanks.